# How to use distinct on only two columns

Tags: java, db2

I have this data on the table:

`CARID  MAKECODE MODELCODE   YEAR COSTCODE VIN                 CURRVALUE
123456 NISS     MAX         2013 1        AAMBF45V5A5619007    30000.00
123457 NISS     MAX         2013 1        ABMBF4DV423459007    30000.00
123458 NISS     MAX         2013 1        ACMBF4D15A5319007    30000.00
123459 FORD     FOC         2013 2        BAB7DF5665A1SD465    30000.00
123460 FORD     FOC         2013 2        BBF7DF563453SDF65    30000.00
123461 FORD     FOC         2013 2        BCF7DF5624A1SDF65    30000.00
123462 CHEV     MAL         2013 3        CAMB456V223456454    30000.00
123463 CHEV     MAL         2013 3        CBMB456V223456454    30000.00
123464 CHEV     MAL         2013 3        CCMB456V223456454    30000.00
123465 DODG     GRA         2013 4        DADF895OIU2452D25    30000.00
123466 DODG     GRA         2013 4        DBDF895OIU2452D25    30000.00
123467 DODG     GRA         2013 4        DCDF895OIU2452D25    30000.00
123468 TOYO     COR         2013 5        EA765SADF985SAD6D    30000.00
123469 TOYO     COR         2013 5        EB765SADF985SAD6D    30000.00
123470 TOYO     COR         2013 5        EC765SADF985SAD6D    30000.00
123471 TOYO     RAV         2013 6        FA45H45K3HJ4K5H4K    30000.00
123472 TOYO     RAV         2013 6        FB45H45K3HJ4K5H4K    30000.00
123473 TOYO     RAV         2013 6        FC45H45K3HJ4K5H4K    30000.00
123474 CHEV     EQU         2013 7        GA8754DF876SAD876    30000.00
123475 CHEV     EQU         2013 7        GB8754DF876SAD876    30000.00
123476 CHEV     EQU         2013 7        GC8754DF876SAD876    30000.00`

What I would like returned is:

`CARID  MAKECODE MODELCODE   YEAR COSTCODE VIN                 CURRVALUE
123456 NISS     MAX         2013 1        AAMBF45V5A5619007    30000.00
123459 FORD     FOC         2013 2        BAB7DF5665A1SD465    30000.00
123462 CHEV     MAL         2013 3        CAMB456V223456454    30000.00
123465 DODG     GRA         2013 4        DADF895OIU2452D25    30000.00
123468 TOYO     COR         2013 5        EA765SADF985SAD6D    30000.00
123471 TOYO     RAV         2013 6        FA45H45K3HJ4K5H4K    30000.00
123474 CHEV     EQU         2013 7        GA8754DF876SAD876    30000.00`

I am accessing the DB2 database from a java application and excluding the cars that are unavailable for dates entered using this query:

```
SELECT A.CARID, B.CATEGORY, C.MAKEDESC, D.MODELDESC, A.YEAR, B.PERDAY, A.CURRVALUE
             FROM SCM.CAR_INV A
             INNER JOIN SCM.CAR_COST B ON A.COSTCODE = B.COSTCODE
             INNER JOIN SCM.CAR_MAKE C ON A.MAKECODE = C.MAKECODE
             INNER JOIN SCM.CAR_MODEL D ON A.MODELCODE = D.MODELCODE
             WHERE NOT CARID IN (SELECT CARID
             FROM SCM.CAR_RESERV
             WHERE ((PICKUP BETWEEN ? AND ?)
             OR (DROPOFF BETWEEN ? AND ?))
             OR (? BETWEEN PICKUP AND DROPOFF
             OR (? BETWEEN PICKUP AND DROPOFF)))
```

So what I would like to so is apply the DISTINCT to only the MAKEDESC and MODELDESC columns which would return the first Car ID found and skip over any ID's after that with the same make and model.

Comment: You can't, because you have to tell the system what single value you want for all _other_ columns.  You can do this by putting a `GROUP BY` on just those two columns and an aggregate on everything else, but there's usually better options.  Like wrapping the access to `CAR_INV` in a CTE and using a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] query, which is what this is.  Side note, don't use `BETWEEN` [with things like date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), and there's a two-compare way for overlapping ranges.

Answer (score 0):

If you want apply DISTINCT on MAKEDESC and MODELDESC
use:
 GROUP BY MAKEDESC, MODELDESC

Comment: ... except then he'd need to use an aggregate function on all the other columns.